# Python requests, PUT empty data

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use request to PUT some data as such,

```
r = requests.put(
        url,
        data={'tiles': []},
        headers={'x-auth-token': token}
    )
```

However, `tiles` is not sent if it is just an empty list. `tiles` only appears when the data is not empty. I checked this with http://httpbin.org/put also.

Does anyone have any ideas how to put empty data?

Comment: You mean `'tiles': []`? Why are you setting it to an empty list? A list is seen as 0 or more values for the parameter, so `'tiles': ['foo', 'bar']` becomes `tiles=foo` and `tiles=bar`.

Answer (score 4):

Naturally I figured it out immediately after asking. I wanted to use `json` inplace of `data`.

```
r = requests.put(
        url,
        json={'tiles': []},
        headers={'x-auth-token': token}
    )
```

Comment: That's a very different datatype!

Comment: Is it just me, or is this undocumented for `requests.put()`? I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that you can pass a `json=` keyword argument in place of `data=`. This helped though, so thanks!